# How to get Phone IDLE State after Incoming call is disconnected?

Tags: android

I can easily get an IDLE state when incoming call get disconnect using PhoneStateListener But I need an IDLE Phone state of Incoming call And condition are : Suppose incoming call is in progress and someone give missed call in between. Every time i get first Missed call IDLE state and then Incoming disconnected IDLE state. Is there any idea to identify which Phone IDLE state is executing?.

Your answer would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: The 'python-idle' tag is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is maintain a flag value for each state & then use it in EXTRA_STATE_IDLE to know if its a 1st call or when call is call is currently going on -

```
if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {           
                      ring =true;  

            }
if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
         {
                callReceived=true;
          }
```

and then in idle state use these two flags to know which call it is -

```
 if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                      // If phone was ringing(ring=true) and received(callReceived=true) 
                       if(ring==true&&callReceived==true)
                       {
                          Log.i("Detect","Call is currently going on");
                       }
          }
```