# How to get the disconnected cause from the calls in CallLog.Calls

Tags: android, telephonymanager, calllog

I am trying to show the disconnected cause for every call in the call log if it is disconnected . Is there any way to get that from existing call logs or is there any other way to get the disconnected cause like while making an outgoing call ? .

For Example : 
 I want to know why an outgoing call got ended while ringing . If it is a network issue i will make an entry in my existing table else if it is intentionally ended by receiving user then i have to ignore it .

Comment: Could you please explain in greater detail what you mean by "disconnected cause"? Do you want to know if the local or remote phone finished the call?

Comment: @Thomas , in some cases a call might get disconnected due to network  issues or maybe if the call receiving user ends the call or he didn't even pick it up in the first place. so i want to know whats the reason a call got terminated. i need the cause of the termination in the caller's mobile so that i can add remaining functionality based on this.

Comment: I see. I don't think this is possible solely with CallLog, bit you might try using PhoneStateListener. Take a look at the following answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533783/5956451